# Infinite loop while calling a relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I have a model `Membership`:

```
protected $appends = [
    'can_change_payment_methods'
];

public function getCanChangePaymentMethodsAttribute(): Bool
{
    $this->service; // Just calling that infinite loop as an attribute
    return false; // Temporary return statement, of course
}

public function contact(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class);
}

public function getServiceAttribute()
{
   return $this->contact->service;
   // This is what triggers the infinite loop
}
```

This is a standard behavior that I've done a thousand times. At least I think I have.

`Contact model`

```
public function service(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Service::class);
}
```

No matter how I call Membership's service attribute or if I make it into a simple function `getService()` it always goes into an infinite loop. Is there some Eloquent quirk I'm missing here?

Comment: Problems like this are usually the result of a cycle in your `$appends` or `$with` model properties. You are showing one `$appends` here which (based on what you shared) should not seemingly cause any problem but if e.g. you have a `$with = [ 'membership' ]` in your contact model for example then this issue will happen. Currently it's not clear what the cause is so I suggest you enable XDEBUG and set a maximum call stack depth of something like 300 and check the stack trace on when it fails due to too deep recursion

Comment: Yes, I do have with membership on my Contact model! So this is the culprit then. However I need both with and appends, I think, since this is all passed to Inertia and needs to be preloaded. How can I workround this?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with inertia but generally I would avoid the `$appends` and `$with` properties for this exact reason. Instead if you have the capability do `Membership::with([ 'contact.service' ])`  in your controller and then access the service indirectly via contact or use something like [has one through](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) to define it as a relationship directly on the membership model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think, somewhere in your models, there is infinite recursive calls.
`Contact` model and `Service` model these two models looks like they calls of each other...

check in each of these model probably `Contact` have `$appends` or `$with`  `Service` at the same time `Service` have `$appends` or `$with` `Contact` so they call each other endlessly

below threads about same problem might help you
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19479

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21506

https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/5ukuvr/54_manytomany_infiniteloop_problem_with_appends/